# Send a word at start of an align environment to the left

Tags: align, enumerate

I would like to send the word "Associativity" in my equation to the left in this enumerate environment like this:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm}
\pagestyle{empty}
\newcommand\Item[1][]{%
\ifx\relax#1\relax  \item \else \item[#1] \fi
\abovedisplayskip=0pt\abovedisplayshortskip=0pt~\vspace*{-\baselineskip}}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}%[align=left,style=nextline,leftmargin=*,labelsep=\parindent,label=\textbf{(\alph*)}]
\Item 
\begin{align*}
Associativity:\hspace{1cm}&\forall~\alpha,~\beta,\gamma~\epsilon~\digamma\\
(\alpha+\beta)+\gamma & = \alpha+(\beta +\gamma )\\
(\alpha\cdot\beta)\cdot\gamma & = \alpha\cdot(\beta \cdot\gamma )
\end{align*}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another, rather simple solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb}
\usepackage[margin=30mm,showframe]{geometry}

    \begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item  
 Associativity:\qquad  $\begin{aligned}[t]
                        \forall~& \alpha,~\beta,\gamma~\epsilon~\digamma    \\
(\alpha+\beta)+\gamma           & = \alpha+(\beta +\gamma)                  \\
(\alpha\cdot\beta)\cdot\gamma   & = \alpha\cdot(\beta\cdot\gamma)
                        \end{aligned}$
\end{enumerate}
    \end{document}
```

which gives:

[image]

For it is necessary package `mathtools`, which define environment `aligned`. Special item is not necessary, above solution works with any list.

Answer (score 4):

You could place the word "Associativity" after `\Item` and before `\begin{align*}`. Also, do make sure to remove the instruction `\hspace{1cm}`.

Incidentally, I suspect that you should be writing `\in` instead of `\epsilon`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm}
\pagestyle{empty}
\newcommand\Item[1][]{%
\ifx\relax#1\relax  \item \else \item[#1] \fi
\abovedisplayskip=0pt\abovedisplayshortskip=0pt~\vspace*{-\baselineskip}}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\Item \emph{Associativity}:
\begin{align*}
&\forall~\alpha,~\beta,\gamma~\epsilon~\digamma\\
(\alpha+\beta)+\gamma & = \alpha+(\beta +\gamma )\\
(\alpha\cdot\beta)\cdot\gamma & = \alpha\cdot(\beta \cdot\gamma )
\end{align*}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would do it with the `alignedat` environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm}
\pagestyle{empty}
\newcommand\Item[1][]{%
\ifx\relax#1\relax \item \else \item[#1] \fi
\abovedisplayskip=0pt\abovedisplayshortskip=0pt~\vspace*{-\baselineskip}}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}%
\Item Associativity:\quad
$\begin{alignedat}[t]{2}
 & \forall~\alpha,~\beta,\gamma\in\digamma, & \quad (\alpha+\beta)+\gamma & = \alpha+(\beta +\gamma )\\
 & & (\alpha\cdot\beta)\cdot\gamma & = \alpha\cdot(\beta \cdot\gamma )
\end{alignedat} $
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]